# A Refinement of Hermite-Hadamard Integral inequalities

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

As you know, **Hermite-Hadamard Integral inequalities** gives lower and upper bounds for integrals of convex functions.

Now, let's assume that $f(x)$ and $f^{k}(x)$($k$ th derivate of $f(x)$) are convex functions on the interval $[a,b]$. Is there a refinement of Hermite- Hadamard inequalities for

$$\int^b_a f(x) dx?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many improvements, enhancements and analogies of this celebrated inequality. The exhausting study is given by Dragomir, Peirce and Pecaric in this monograph http://rgmia.org/papers/monographs/Master.pdf

Also Croatian Pecarić's team deals with inequalities of HH type. Many papers are published in *Mathematical Inequalities and Applications*.

If you have an access, you could consult Mathematical Reviews (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/).

During my reviewing career I have seen many inequalities of this type. But there are too many of them to give the precise answer. Here I would like to say that such results almost surely exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you give a link to a paper that you think giving a good refinement for a function I described? :)

Comment: Do you have an access to Mathematical Reviews? If yes, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't got an access :( Thanks for your help. Do you think I can find a good estimation for my function in the monograph?

Comment: This paper for instance https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1029-242X-2013-451 This is open access. Search also arXiv.

When I asked Mathscinet for papers with titles containing "Hermite-Hadamard" together with "derivative" I obtained 40 results.

Concerninig the 2nd part of your question...it depends on what kind of results do you expect. Please inspect some papers to fint the siprit.

Your university should have Mathscinet access.

Comment: http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/Article.aspx?ID=0354-51801308575L&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

and

http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2013/ams-121-124-2013/39520.html

These papers treat n-th order derivatves but in the context of certain generalizations of convexity.